# Multiple tables into a view usning mvc 5 razor

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have multiple tables that I want to put in a single View, I have created a model diagram for them, I can create the controller to view data from 1 table with a search box but I want to know how can I add data from other tables using the same search box in the same table. It uses a serial number to check for some test results in the tables. Thanks in advance for your support

Comment: Please add your action code and view content!

Answer (score 0):

If you need to search multiple tables, you'll need to query each of those tables individually and return the results to the view together. You can combine the results from the various queries either by:

1. If all the entities representing these tables can inherit from a common base class or implement the same interface, you can return a collection of that base class/interface to the view. For example:

   ```
   var combined = new List<Pet>();
   combined.AddRange(db.Cats.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchTerm)));
   combined.AddRange(db.Dogs.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchTerm)));
   return View(combined);
   ```

   *Assuming both `Cat` and `Dog` inherited from `Pet`*
2. You can create a class to use as view model like `SearchResultViewModel` and map the data from each query to instances of that before returning your collection of `SearchResultViewModel` instances to the view. For example:

   ```
   var results = new List<SearchResultViewModel>();
   var catResults = db.Cats.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).Select(m => new SearchResultViewModel
   {
       Title = m.Name
   });
   var dogResults = db.Dogs.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchTerm)).Select(m => new SearchResultViewModel
   {
       Title = m.Name
   });
   results.AddRange(catResults);
   results.AddRange(dogResults);
   return View(results);
   ```

However, both of these approaches are a bit arduous, and involve multiple queries which scale as the number of tables you need to search scale. Typically, when you reach the point in your application where you need to do this type of thing, you'll start to lean on a true search engine solution. There's a number of choices out there, but my personal fave is [Elasticsearch](http://www.elasticsearch.org/), which while Java-based, has third-party .NET support via various Nuget packages, the best of which, in my opinion (and StackOverflow's apparently as well), is [NEST](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/).

**UPDATE**

Let's assume you employ a base class. Based on the properties you mentioned, you'd have something like:

```
public class Pet
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string HairColor { get; set; }
}

public class Cat : Pet
{
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class Dog : Pet
{
    string Breed { get; set; }
}
```

Then, based on this, you could take one of the two steps above I mentioned:

1. Use the base class. This means you will only be able to work with the fields common between the two after you combine them into one dataset, i.e. the properties on `Pet`.

   ```
   var combined = new List<Pet>();
   combined.AddRange(db.Cats.Where(m => m.HairColor == hairColorQuery)));
   combined.AddRange(db.Dogs.Where(m => m.HairColor == hairColorQuery)));
   return View(combined);
   ```

   In your view:

   ```
   @model List<Namespace.To.Pet>

   <p>Matching results:</p>

   <ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <li>@item.Name</li>
   }
   </ul>
   ```

   Like I said, you can only work with the common properties, so you would be unable to get at the `Breed` property of an item, because `Cat` (at least in this example) does not have that, only `Dog`.
2. Use a view model. This gives you a bit more flexibility, as you can both map values from one property to a different property and use nullables to present information when you have it. For this example, to show the idea of mapping, let's say that instead of `Age` like `Cat` has, `Dog` has a property called `BirthDay` instead.

   ```
   public class PetSearchResult
   {
       public string Name { get; set; }
       public string Breed { get; set; }
       public int Age { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   Then, in your action:

   ```
   var results = new List<PetSearchResult>();
   var catResults = db.Cats.Where(m => m.HairColor == hairColorQuery).Select(m => new PetSearchResult
   {
       Name = m.Name,
       Age = m.Age
   });
   var dogResults = db.Dogs.Where(m => m.HairColor == hairColorQuery).Select(m => new PetSearchResult
   {
       Name = m.Name,
       // I know this doesn't work for leaps years and such. It's just illustrative
       Age = DateTime.Today.Subtract(m.BirthDay).Days / 365,
       Breed = m.Breed
   });
   results.AddRange(catResults);
   results.AddRange(dogResults);

   return View(results);
   ```

   Finally, in your view:

   ```
   @model List<Namespace.To.PetSearchResult>

   <p>Matching results:</p>

   <ul>
   @foreach (var item in Model)
   {
       <li>
           Name: @item.Name<br/>
           Age: @item.Age<br/>
           @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Breed))
           {
               Breed: @item.Breed
           }
       </li>
   }
   ```

   Both the items created from `Cat` instances and the those created from `Dog` instances can show `Age`, because in the case of `Dog`, we calculated the age from the birthday. In items created from `Dog` instances, `Breed` will have a value, and in those cases we can show that value. Items created from `Cat` instances will never have a value for `Breed` because that datapoint didn't exist, but this shows how you can work a bit of flexibility into it.

All that said, I want to re-iterate that although you can do it one of these ways, it should be apparent the complexity involved even with these relatively simple classes. Really, you should introduce a true search engine solution for this kind of thing.

Comment: Hi Chris, Thanks for the answer, but I still have a doubt, if I have a cats table with the fields Name, Age, and hair color, and the dogs table with the fields Breed, name and hair color (diferent fields) can you tell me how it would be the model, controller and view if I wanted to see all the pets of a specific hair color? Thanks in advance for your help